# Sequential execution of command in shell script and delay the next statement to execute

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, database-backups

I'm trying to write a script to make a database backup. The backup script is as follow -

```
$LOG_TIME=`date +%T`
$LOG=/home/developer/backup.log

echo $LOG_TIME "::Backup Started">>$LOG;
su - oracle -c "exp username/password file=~/db_exp.dmp log=db_exp.dmp";
echo $LOG_TIME "::Backup End">>$LOG;
```

My code is making tacking backup perfectly. But when I check the `db_exp.dmp` file I found -

```
14:25:33 :: Backup Started  
14:25:33 :: Backup End
```

My problem is here the two lines "**Backup Started**" and "**Backup End**" printed at same time while it takes few seconds (about 40~50) to taking the backup. I want to print the actual time when the backup completed. I have tried several things like - using **`&&`**; using semicolon (`;`) and `if` statement like -

```
if backup_command; then 
   echo $LOG_TIME ":: Backup End";
fi
```

But nothing worked for me. I don't want to use `sleep` here, because it doesn't give me the actual time of the db backup to complete.

Comment: `$LOG_TIME` value is set once when initialized. You must invoke a new `date` command for the end date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
echo `date +%T` "::Backup End"
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend using `$( ... )` rather than backticks, it's more readable and (for the rare cases you need it) makes nesting easier.

Comment: I agree that `$(...)` is more readable. The drawback is that I'm not sure all shells support it. I prefer to recommend the most widely supported syntax.

Comment: `$( ... )` is at least POSIX, so any shell you're likely to find on a unix machine running an OS from "after 2000" is likely to support it.